# Can't Vertical Align Text With Image In Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to simulate a contact list in Angular Material. The div containing text should vertically align to the center of the avatar image on the left. I have tried several ways to add the layout-align but none of them seem to have any effect. I have included the code and the Plunker URL below to demonstrate my issue. I appreciate all help!

**Plunker:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/W18pV9fOE6BP9SuYQGAm?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item class="md-2-line" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/583390/screenshots/2517460/sob_avatar_illustration__800x600px__1.0_1x.jpg" style="width:60px;" />
    <div class="md-list-item-text">
      <h3>Babe Ruth</h3>
      <p>Baseball Player</p>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>

  <md-list-item class="md-2-line" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/583390/screenshots/2517460/sob_avatar_illustration__800x600px__1.0_1x.jpg" style="width:60px;" />
    <div>
      <h3>Mickey Mantle</h3>
      <p>Baseball Player</p>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>

  <md-list-item class="md-2-line" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/583390/screenshots/2517460/sob_avatar_illustration__800x600px__1.0_1x.jpg" style="width:60px;" />
    <div class="md-list-item-text">
      <h3>Derek Jeter</h3>
      <p>Baseball Player</p>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `class="md-avatar"` to your *img* tags.

Something like

```
<md-list-item class="md-2-line">
  <img class="md-avatar" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/583390/screenshots/2517460/sob_avatar_illustration__800x600px__1.0_1x.jpg" style="width:60px;" />
  <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
    <h3>Derek Jeter</h3>
    <p>Baseball Player</p>
  </div>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: got your back ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's out of line is **because of the margins that are set by the `md-list-item-text`** css class. There may be a better way, but to suggest something different to what's already been suggested, you could **override those styles and reset those margins**.

1) Use this to reset the margin from within your style.css file:

```
md-list-item .no-margin.md-list-item-text {
  margin: 0;
}
```

2) Set that `no-margin` class on each of the divs:

```
<md-list-item class="md-2-line" layout="row" layout-align="center start">
  <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/583390/screenshots/2517460/sob_avatar_illustration__800x600px__1.0_1x.jpg" style="width:60px;" />
  <div class="no-margin md-list-item-text">
    <h3>Babe Ruth</h3>
    <p>Baseball Player</p>
  </div>
</md-list-item>
```

3) Rearrange your style sheet imports for this to work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

`style.css` must come after `angular-material.min.css` so that you can override it.

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0vTNpqZcCjcyKa98K0b9?p=preview)